# Delay in updating live status from text file in django

Tags: django, linux, django-views

I want to update some live status through text file on django html template.
Issue is sometimes delay comes very late, not sure if this is due to linux-server dependencies or something else.
Also, what is recommended location to store live logs for reading purpose, currently I am using static directory in django server.

```
     function update() {
         var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
             document.getElementById("live_status").innerHTML = this.readyState;
             if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                 var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                 x = "{{ details.name }}" + "</br>";
                 for ( i in myObj.users ){
                     for ( j in myObj.users[i].live_status ){
                         x += myObj.users[i].live_status[j] + "</br>";
                     }
                 }
                 document.getElementById("live_status").innerHTML = x;
                 //document.getElementById("live_status").innerHTML = "Test";
             }
         };
         xmlhttp.open("GET", "{% static 'live_status.txt' %}", true);
         xmlhttp.send();
     }
     update();
     setInterval(update, 10000);
```

Comment: Can you define delay?

Comment: In above code I am rechecking file in every 10sec but some times there is delay of 4-5mins to get updates on front end.